# Do I need to install g++ to compile c++ files in Ubuntu 14.04.1?

Tags: 14.04, gcc, c++, g++

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.1
I want to know,

Do I need to install `g++` from the Ubuntu Software Center to compile the c++ files? 
Is `GCC`(GNU Compiler Collection) able to accomplish this instead?

**if the answer for my 1st question is, yes...**

then, why doesn't Ubuntu 14.04 come with a c++ compiler? After all it is also just as important as `GCC`? Why will a c++ compiler not ship with a default Ubuntu installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need g++ to compile c++ programs if you have a set of c++ libs. Installed use the proper library flags. Say we want to use gnu's stdc++:

```
gcc -o target source.cpp -L/usr/lib/architecture & distro dependent/ -lstdc++
```

and for a long time the guiding people of GNU/Linux where c oriented so until some what recently distros had to package a c compiler with the c++ portions optional.  Now I can't say what Ubuntu packages by default since my first command on a new system is often `sudo apt-get update && apt-get install g++`

Comment: is that c++ libraries comes with default ubuntu installtion or not?

Comment: No, not the development versions, you will have to install `libstdc++-dev` at a minimum.  Unless you are bandwidth limited I would suggest going ahead and installing g++

Answer (score 7):

You will need something that can compile C++ files. The two main compilers in Linux are GCC and Clang. GCC is the default compiler in Ubuntu.

GCC isn't installed by default because not everyone needs to compile a file. GCC is typically only used by developers. However, you can easily install it by installing the `build-essential` package, which is a metapackage that installs gcc (for compiling C files), g++ (for compiling C++ files), and the C library headers.

Comment: if gcc is not installed by default,then how we are using gcc to compile c files in terminal... and i need to know whether the gcc(which is installed by default in ubuntu) is enough to compile c++ files..(because i saw in wikipedia,  it is not only gnu c compiler ,it is gnu compiler collection for various languages like c,c++ ..etc)

Comment: The program `gcc` is for compiling C files. GCC as an abbreviation is the GNU Compiler Collection. You need `g++` to compile C++ files (try using `gcc`; you'll get errors). As for the default install of `gcc` but not `g++`, I was under the impression neither are installed by default.